# Jquery Time Picker with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using a JQUERY Time Picker for my PHP reservation system

```
$('#Ttime').timepicker({ 
  'timeFormat': 'h:i A' 
});
```

it works well but when I add the 'disableTimeRanges',

```
$('#Ttime').timepicker({ 
  'timeFormat': 'h:i A'
  'disableTimeRanges': unavailableTime 
});
```

I start having problems with disabling specific time ranges.
Those time ranges are from my database, which I put in arrays

```
$sql="SELECT treatment_time FROM reserve_detail WHERE therapist_ID = '".$q."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = array();
$a = array();
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $rows[] = $data['treatment_time'];
        $time= strtotime($data['treatment_time']);
        $interval = date("h:i A", strtotime('+30 minutes', $time));

        while (list($key, $original) = each($rows)) {
            $a[] = ([$original,$interval]);
            // $a = "['".$original."','".$interval."'],";
            // $b = implode("-",$a);
        }
    }

print json_encode($a);
```

and I call it using AJAX.

```
$("#Ttime").focus(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: '../admin/thname.php',
                data: "q="+id,
                dataType: 'json', 
                async : false,
                success: function(data){
                  unavailableTime = data;
                }
            });
        });
```

It disables/works when I tried hardcoding it like this:

```
var unavailableTime = [["12:00 AM","12:30 AM"],["1:00 AM","01:30 AM"]];
```

but when I use AJAX, it doesn't disables.
I tried using alert on it,

```
success: function(data){
   unavailableTime = data;
   alert(data)
}
```

it shows the time from my database.
Meaning my variable has my data on it.

I've researched about this on the net, I've tried their solutions
but nothing seems to work.

Can anyone please help me with this problem ?

Comment: I think you will need to bind your unavailableTime somehow and repopulate it once you get your ajax response

Comment: This is an age old problem where bindings occur before the ajax call completes. You need to initialize your time picker from within the `success` callback.

Comment: What do you mean by "bind unavailableTime", sir ? sorry. I'm new with jquery. btw, Thank You for the fast response sir.

Comment: @NilotpalBarpujari I tried moving my timepicker code inside my success callback like what you've said. It's fixed ! :) thank you for your responses sir.